# Constructor Parent called in initialization list of contructor Child

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, private

I have a question about calling a constructor in an initialization list of another constructor. For example when looking at code like this:

```
Library::Child::Child
380 (
381  const word& controlName,
382  const argList& args,                         
383  const word& systemName,              
384  const word& constantName            
385 )
386 :       
387  Parent                                        
388  (                                                         
389  args.rootPath(),                                
390  args.caseName(),                              
391  systemName,                                     
392  constantName                                    
394  )
395 {}
```

with the constructor of class `Parent` called in line 387:

```
   30 Library::Parent::Parent
   31 (
   32     const fileName& rootPath, 
   33     const fileName& caseName,
   34     const word& systemName,
   35     const word& constantName
   36 )
   37 :
   38     processorCase_(caseName.find("processor") != string::npos), //private member
   39     rootPath_(rootPath),  //private member
   40     case_(caseName),     //private member
   41     system_(systemName),   //private member
   42     constant_(constantName)  //private member
   43 {}
```

The primary object constructed is of type/class `Library::Child::Child`, but when constructing that object also the constructor `Library::Parent::Parent` of parentclass `Parent` is called and private members of class `Parent` are defined. Since class `Child` does not inherit private member of class `Parent` and furthermore when calling the constructor of class `Parent` no object/variable is declared (see line 387, first code snippet) I don't know what calling the constructor of `Parent` is good for? Furthermore in what connection are the private members of class `Parent` to the class `Child` object and where are they stored since no class `Parent` object is declared?
I tried to find information about it in the net, but could not find anything answering my questions.

greetings
streight

Comment: `Library::Child::Child` is a derived class from the base class `Library::Parent::Parent` ?? (The words `Base` and `Derived` would make this question considerably easier to follow if that is, in fact, the case).

Comment: @WhozCraig : Yes, class `Child`  is derived from class `Parent`. I think this is also very easy to understand and in this case accurate since `Child` inherits directly from `Parent`. Note: `Library::Child::Child` is the constructor and not the class, but I am sure you know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to missunderstand some basic concepts in `c++`. A derived class inherits everything from its parent class. It might not have access to it. It is not like "oh its private so it does not exists".

I think rest of your problems come from this missconception. And maybe from what *declaration* and *definition* mean. You can imagine derivation in `c++` like extending base class. In the memory the `Derived` stuff is kinda glued to `Base`.

The `Derived` stuff would have no sense if no `Base` were present. It is an extension to `Base`. Thus, `Base` class object has always be instantiated. Even if the derived class has no access to it. That is why the constructor of `Base` is called during the construction of `Derived`. It is always called. Even if not explicitly, then implicitly default constructor will be called.

The `Child` constructor calls `Parent` constructor, and does not access any private members. The `Parent::Parent()` does. It does not *define* them it *initialized* them, they are defined in `Parent` class definition.

Also objects are *always* declared. You cannot derive from an undeclared object. Nor you can do anything with an undeclared object. So your `Parent` must be declared, otherwise compiler would throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, I really have missunderstood the inheritance concept a little. So, if I understand you right, for constructing an object of class `derived` ALL parent classes constructors of `derived` are called before calling the constructor of `derived`. The object of `derived` consists of all members of all parents plus its own members, but the access to the private members of the classes is limited to the respective class members, right? Therefore in my case the object of class `Child` has the privare members of class `Parent`, just the members of class `Child` have no access to them.

Comment: @Streight Right. Also *members* usually mean variables in class, functions are called *methods*. So members usually don't do anything to other members so they don't access other members, but methods do operate on them.

Comment: I prefer to say membervariables and membermethods since they are both members of the class. Therefore membermethods can access membervariables etcetera.